# SVG with multiple path tags ends up ignoring fill color in IE when base64 encoded

Tags: css, svg, base64, internet-explorer-11

I have an svg which is base64 encoded and used as a background image. This is the code for the SVG:

```css
body {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Something" data-name="Something" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            path {
                fill: #FFF !important;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <title>Example</title>
    <path class="cls-1" d="M16.79,17.28c-.08-1.78-.27-3.55-.33-5.32-.09-2.52,0-5-.3-7.52-.06-.54-.1-1.08-.12-1.62s.05-.72-.44-.81a21.21,21.21,0,0,0-2.15,0C12,1.94,10.48,2,9,2c-.35,0-.73-.14-.94.24A3.28,3.28,0,0,0,8,3.47,37.06,37.06,0,0,0,8,7.86,4.07,4.07,0,0,0,6.78,8,9.14,9.14,0,0,1,5.26,8,10.49,10.49,0,0,0,3.59,8c-.49.05-.39.34-.37.78,0,.62.13,1.21.2,1.83a23.4,23.4,0,0,1,0,4c0,.74,0,1.48-.07,2.22,0,.45-.06.84.45.92a6.36,6.36,0,0,0,1.41-.13,15.25,15.25,0,0,1,2.1-.11,4.07,4.07,0,0,1,.61,0c.11.08,0,.23.11.32.26.23.88,0,1.18,0,.67,0,1.32,0,2,0,1.23-.12,2.48.14,3.72,0C15.34,17.9,17,18.1,16.79,17.28Zm-3.24-2.7h0Zm.31-.06,0,.3M8.33,16.88A8.87,8.87,0,0,0,8.56,15c.05-.47,0-.94,0-1.41,0-1.07.07-2.13.1-3.2,0-1.39,0-2.78.07-4.17,0-.71.06-1.42.05-2.13a4.69,4.69,0,0,1,0-1.26c0-.08.75,0,.83,0a21,21,0,0,0,2.25-.1c.94,0,1.88,0,2.82-.11.11,0,.61-.16.71-.07s.09,1.16.12,1.39a25.86,25.86,0,0,1,.28,3.86c0,1.2-.11,2.39-.12,3.59s0,2.63.08,3.95a7,7,0,0,1,.11,1.43c0,.22,0,.1-.13.2a3.62,3.62,0,0,1-1.4,0,9.35,9.35,0,0,1,0-1.36,3.22,3.22,0,0,0-.17-1.42c-.22-.31-.59-.18-.9-.13a9.39,9.39,0,0,1-1.55.11c-.7,0-.77.36-.77,1s0,1-.05,1.45A1.13,1.13,0,0,1,11,17c-.17.27-.87.15-1.23.17S8.12,17.56,8.33,16.88ZM7.14,15a4.09,4.09,0,0,1,0,1.65c-.12.39.17.14-.25.31s-.29.12-.44-.14a3.33,3.33,0,0,1-.06-1.5c0-.35.08-.73.56-.51C7.19,14.88,7,14.7,7.14,15Zm.52,2.18c0-.7,0-1.41,0-2.11s-.26-.82-.86-.79-.88.1-1,.8a6.25,6.25,0,0,0,0,1.06,4.44,4.44,0,0,1,.1.95c-.33,0-1.66,0-1.79-.22s0-.54,0-.71,0-.62,0-.93c0-.51-.06-1-.08-1.53-.06-1.07.05-2.09.08-3.16,0-.45-.09-.92-.07-1.37,0-.07,0-.24,0-.29a4.3,4.3,0,0,1,1.29-.2,8.79,8.79,0,0,0,2.75-.38,21.64,21.64,0,0,1,0,2.72C8.07,12,8,13.13,8,14.21c0,.63-.1,1.24-.1,1.86,0,.18.07.4.06.57s-.12.35-.13.54Zm5.2.12c-.34.08-1.29.25-1.43-.08a5.2,5.2,0,0,1,.12-1.6c0-.25,0-.58.17-.69s.64.08.81.08a6.72,6.72,0,0,0,1-.1,10.65,10.65,0,0,1,0,1.78C13.55,17.19,13.39,17.14,12.87,17.27Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M10.29,5.76c.85,0,.63-.84.58-1.45-.07-.89-.93-.25-1-.4-.15-.32-.35,0-.4.15A5,5,0,0,0,9.39,5C9.3,5.72,9.61,5.75,10.29,5.76ZM9.93,4.33a3.5,3.5,0,0,1,.51-.13,3.23,3.23,0,0,1,0,.8c-.09.3.07.18-.22.26-.58.16-.46-.54-.56-.94Z" />
</svg>
```

In chrome/firefox the background render with white color but in IE the "path" is always black. If I remove the second "path" tag the image renders with correct colors. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you have two identical paths, identically styled, one on top of the other anyway? If removing one of them solves you problem, then do it.

Comment: @ccprog that was just an example to demonstrate the problem, updated my question.

Comment: You are Base64 encoding this SVG? What are you doing with it then?